# Customize Forge BimWalkExtension keyboard inputs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to change the keys used in bimwalkExtensions to move in 3D model.
I did not find a method to override keycontrols in the doc

[Current configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilzAe.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's no option for overriding for now.